# How to use threadpoolexecutor to run two tests and send the result of one as a parameter to the other in python

Tags: python, automated-tests, threadpoolexecutor

I am using ThreadPoolExecutor to run two tests simultaneously in python, for some tests, however I have a problem, and that is that let's say there is a main test and a secondary test, both will be executed from the beginning, however the secondary test will finish first, I return the result, to later use it as a parameter in the main test, since by the time I require it I have already finished the secondary test, but I don't see how to apply that.

I am using Selenium to do the test, and from my main.py file I send it to call the methods, so I have my code.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def PruebaPrincipal(opcion_sistema, opcion_ambiente, opcion_usuario, opcion_especifica, tipo_de_credito, resultado_folio):
                        resultado_folio = resultado_folio_future.result()
                        with Flujos_obligatorios_originacion() as bot1:
                            limpiar_pantalla()
                            bot1.get_url(opcion_sistema, opcion_ambiente)
                            bot1.iniciar_sesion(opcion_ambiente, opcion_usuario)
                            bot1.Crear_Solicitud(tipo_de_credito)
                            resultado_database = bot1.Establecer_base_de_datos(opcion_ambiente)
                            curp_cliente = bot1.Llenar_Formulario_Solicitud(opcion_sistema, opcion_especifica, resultado_database, opcion_ambiente)
                            bot1.Solicitud_Tipo_de_Credito(tipo_de_credito)
                            bot1.Solicitud_Datos_del_Credito(resultado_folio, resultado_database, curp_cliente, tipo_de_credito)
                            bot1.cerrar_sesion()
                            bot1.close()

def PruebaSecundaria(opcion_ambiente, opcion_sistema):
                       with Flujos_obligatorios_originacion() as bot2:
                            resultado_folio_future = bot2.Obtener_Folio_Nav(opcion_ambiente, opcion_sistema)
                            return resultado_folio_future

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
                       resultado_folio_future = executor.submit(PruebaSecundaria, opcion_ambiente, opcion_sistema)
                       executor.submit(PruebaPrincipal, opcion_sistema, opcion_ambiente, opcion_usuario, opcion_especifica, tipo_de_credito, resultado_folio_future)
```

I hope that the secondary test obtains a value for me to use in the main test, sending it as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. You get a [`Future`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future) from `executor.submit()`; calling [`.result()`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future.result) on a future waits for the future to have completed and returns the value (or raises an exception if the future failed).

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, Future


def Suma(valor1: int, valor2: int):
    resultado_suma = valor1 + valor2
    print(f"El resultado de la suma es: {resultado_suma}")
    return resultado_suma


def Multiplicacion(resultado_suma: Future):
    resultado_multiplicacion = resultado_suma.result() * 2
    print(f"El resultado de la multiplicacion es: {resultado_multiplicacion}")
    return resultado_multiplicacion + 15


with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    sum_future = executor.submit(Suma, 5, 5)
    mult_future = executor.submit(Multiplicacion, sum_future)
    print("Final result:", mult_future.result())
```

This prints out

```
El resultado de la suma es: 10
El resultado de la multiplicacion es: 20
Final result: 35
```

Comment: In fact, I have just modified my code to show it in more detail, I ensure that the two tests are executed at the same time (to reduce execution time) and since the secondary test would finish first, by the time the main test requires the result_folio it will already be finished. secondary test.

Comment: @ImGodsGamerZ I'm not sure how this changes the situation?